# How to thread a background task whilst changing the cursor to WAIT in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, background-task

I have an application which upon login accesses a database through an interface class. The login process causes the application to not respond for a  period while it hits the database and therefore I have been looking into threads and the waiting cursor to allow this to run smoothly. I have attempted to use threading via many of the examples on the web and stack overflow but my method doesn't seem to be working, I receive the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4 exception, and am not sure how to proceed from here. What I am attempting to do is to change the cursor to WAIT mode whilst this background thread is running the loginLoadEverything() method (although I haven't included the code within it as it is too long). Here is my controller class:

```
package main.java.gui;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import main.java.databaseInterface.BackendInterface;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class LoginController implements Initializable {


    private BackendInterface backendInterface;
    private DashboardController dashboardController;
    private StudentsController studentsController;
    private ConsultationController consultationController;
    private CreateStudentController createStudentController;
    private CreateConsultationController createConsultationController;

    @FXML
    TextField username;

    @FXML
    PasswordField password;

    @FXML
    Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    Label loginLabel;

    @FXML
    public void loginButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {

        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {

                        loginLoadEverything();

                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {

                                    Scene s1 = loginLabel.getScene();
                                    s1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

                                } finally {
                                    latch.countDown();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        latch.await();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();

    }

    public void loginLoadEverything() {

         //chance to true when complete
    if (username.getText().isEmpty() == false || password.getText().isEmpty() == false) {

        loginLabel.setText("Please enter data in the fields below");

    } else {

        username.setText("-----");
        password.setText("-----");
        //initialises backend interface with username and password
        backendInterface = new BackendInterface(username.getText(), password.getText().toCharArray());

        // Open a connection to the database

        if (backendInterface.openConnection()) {

            //return and print response
            System.out.println(backendInterface.getConnectionResponse());

            //directs the user to the dashboard after successful login
            try {
                if (backendInterface.getAllStudents() &&
                        backendInterface.getAllConsultations() &&
                        backendInterface.getCourses() &&
                        backendInterface.getConsultationCategories() &&
                        backendInterface.getConsultationPriorities()) {


                    FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();
                    loader1.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/main/res/dashboard.fxml"));
                    loader1.load();
                    Parent p = loader1.getRoot();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
                    stage.show();

                    //set instances to the dashboard controller
                    dashboardController = loader1.getController();
                    dashboardController.setBackendInterface(backendInterface); //pass backendInterface object to controller
                    dashboardController.setDashboardController(loader1.getController()); //pass dashboard as reference

                    //load images
                    Image logoutImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/logout.png"));
                    Image userImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/users.png"));
                    Image calendarImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/calendar.png"));
                    Image leftArrowImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/leftArrow.png"));
                    Image notepadImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/notepad.png"));

                    //set images
                    dashboardController.studentLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(userImage));
                    dashboardController.logoutLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(logoutImage));
                    dashboardController.consultationLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(notepadImage));

    } else {
           system.out.println(backendInterface.getExceptionMessage);
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



}
```

Comment: The `call()` method is the method that is executed on the background thread. It should do the work that takes a long time to execute, and **must not** perform any UI work. Right now, it seems it only does the UI work. Where is the actual database connection work done, it is not clear from your code where that is. There are other problems too - e.g. you change the cursor to `WAIT` *after* everything else in the `call()` method is complete,  which is surely not what you want. But you need to clarify where the actual time-consuming work is first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback James, I have added the rest of the code for loginLoadEverything method. This method provides access to the database from the BackendInterface class. As you can see the methods from the BackendInterface class are called here creating the time-consuming work. I then attempt to call this loginLoadEverything method in the call() method. And yes that is correct, I will have to change the cursor to wait in a more appropriate way to reflect the time-consuming process but not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: See answer. It looks like you need to restructure some of your code as there isn't enough clean separation between the database access and the UI. You need to be able to do all the background work in one chunk of code and encapsulate the results in some kind of object - it's not clear if your `backendInterface` object would work for that or not. Then the task can do the database work and return that object, and the `onSucceeded` handler can show the UI, configuring it from the object. The cursor is trivial once you have that working.

Comment: Updated answer using the code you added. Some of your code is not really understandable. What does `dashboardController.setDashboardController(loader1.getController());` do? Surely this is equivalent to `dashboardController.setDashboardController(dashboardController);`. Why are you giving an object a reference to itself??? And presumably you don't really want to always pass `"-----"` as the username and password? Lots of your instance variables should really be local variables too.

Comment: dashboardController.setDashboardController(loader.getController()); is equivalent to passing the controller to itself. It was code left in there when I was attempting something else. And yes, I don't actually use the "------" as the username and password, I replaced it as I have my actual username and password in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need a `Service` here: you just need a `Task`.

The `call()` method is the method executed on the background thread. It should do the work that takes a long time to execute (i.e. connecting to the database and getting the data from it) and it **must not** do any UI work, as changes to the UI **must** be made on the FX Application Thread. The reason you are getting the exception is that you are creating and showing a `Stage` from the background thread.

So the basic idea is to have the task get the data from the database and return it; then use the `onSucceeded` handler for the task to display the UI, using the results of the task. (The `onSucceeded` handler is executed on the FX Application Thread, allowing you to safely modify the UI here.)

I don't know exactly how your classes are implemented, etc, but something along the following lines might work. The important thing is that you don't do anything in the background thread that interacts with the UI.

```
@FXML
public void loginButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {

    if (( ! username.getText().isEmpty()) || (! password.getText().isEmpty()) ) {

        loginLabel.setText("Please enter data in the fields below");

    } else {

        // I assume you want these values before you set them to "-----", no???
        final String uName = username.getText();
        final char[] pw = password.getText().toCharArray();

        username.setText("-----");
        password.setText("-----");

        // create task for retrieving data:

        Task<BackendInterface> loadDataTask = new Task<BackendInterface>() {

            @Override
            public BackendInterface call() throws Exception {

                BackendInterface backendInterface = new BackendInterface(uName, pw);
                if (backendInterface.openConnection()) {

                    if (backendInterface.getAllStudents() &&
                        backendInterface.getAllConsultations() &&
                        backendInterface.getCourses() &&
                        backendInterface.getConsultationCategories() &&
                        backendInterface.getConsultationPriorities()) {

                        return backendInterface ;
                    }
                 }

                 // maybe throw an exception here, depending on your requirements...
                 return null ;
            }

        };

        // show UI on task completion:

    loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {

        BackendInterface backendInterface = loadDataTask.getValue();

        if (backendInterface == null) {
            // something went wrong... bail, or probably show error message...
            return ;
        }

        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();
        loader1.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/main/res/dashboard.fxml"));
        Parent p = loader1.load();
        DashboardController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setBackendInterface(backendInterface);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
        stage.show();

        // etc etc with your Images, etc (not sure why this isn't done in DashboardController though...)

        // set cursor back to default:
        loginLabel.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    });

    loadDataTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        // show error message or otherwise handle database exception here
    });

    // set cursor to WAIT:
    loginLabel.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

    // and run task in a background thread:
    Thread t = new Thread(loadDataTask);
    t.start();

}
```

Comment: James_D you are a legend, have been struggling with this for days. The return values for the database methods were all boolean values, indicating whether or not the database methods worked or if there was an error. So I changed the datatype in the Task and call() method to Boolean, with the call method returning the value of calling these database connection methods. Then proceeded with loading the dashboard page if this was true. The cursor changes to WAIT and back to DEFAULT too :D